# Using "public boolean contains(CharSequence s) " in ignoreCase

Tags: java

I have found that

```
 public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

Can not be used if the case of the object your trying to find needs to be case ***insensitive***

The method

```
 public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)
```

Is pretty much what I am trying to find, as for my use the first part of the string will be known (The case will not be known) but the second part an variable.

Is their something I am missing here? 
Or can I have some guidance on how to achieve the effect I am looking for

Comment: I think you mean "needs to be case insensitive"...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your input to lower case before testing it against a lower case pattern:

```
yourString.toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
String mystring = "HiHelloWorld";
    String stringIKnow = "hi";
    System.out.println(mystring.toLowerCase().contains(
            stringIKnow.toLowerCase()));
```

As you say, "for my use the first part of the string will be known", you could use startsWith method of string if its a know prefix in advance like below:

```
String mystring = "HiHelloWorld";
    String stringIKnow = "hi";
    System.out.println(mystring.toLowerCase().startsWith(
            stringIKnow.toLowerCase()));
```